# What romaji system should be used?

Tags: discussion, romaji

Since there are [multiple romaji systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese#Modern_systems) in common use, would it be best to standardize on one, and edit questions/answers to conform to it when the romaji system itself is not the point of the question?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we should have a standard romaji system.  Most of them are mutually understandable, and enforcing such a rule would be a huge amount of work with little practical benefit.

That said, I do like Mark Hosang's idea of trying to use the same system as the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

Hepburn seems to be the official standard used at Japanese gov. offices.

Comment: Yes, but should we aggressively standardize non-hepburn romaji?

Comment: ah sorry.  Personally I don't think we should aggressively standardize it.  Mainly because most people who know Japanese are going to be able to read all the variations anyways.

However, it may be a good point to standardize the romaji in Answers to conform to the OPs standard such that OP doesn't get confused.  Though i can see this being a nightmare to enforce.

Comment: It's perhaps a government standard, but in practice I see Japanese people using something closer to nihon-siki (sometimes even to the extent of typing out ッ as xtu), perhaps due to being used to only having to type in ro-mazi when using an IME, and nihon-siki being perhaps the only "standard" romanization system that is completely unambiguous. Personally I'd prefer to see no ro-mazi at all, but if it has to be used, I'd rather see ro-mazi that has a 1:1 mapping to kana.

Comment: @Matti yep wikipedia seems to agree with you, besides learning the nihon-siki has the advantage of being able to use the ten-key system more easily. although i prefer the hepburn

Answer (score 0):

Most people use Hepburn (I like something phonemic like Yale, better, but whatever). I think calling Hepburn standard but not enforcing is a good idea because of search issues. Maybe this should be a separate question, but what will happen when people start to search the site? If they search "八", will they find the questions that used はち, hachi and hati? That could be a serious issue.

Comment: why don't you repost that question over in Meta?